# Is pouring down on a lager yeast cake any different from pouring down on an ale yeast cake?

Tags: reusing-yeast

I've made [pouring down on the yeast cake of a prior batch](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/1832/should-i-ferment-a-new-batch-directly-on-the-yeast-cake-generated-by-the-previous) my standard way of making big beers.  Now I'm moving into lagers and I want to know if there's any difference. Lagers have a much higher recommended pitching rate, so I'd assume that pouring down is a good idea as long as trub doesn't become an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pitch rate for lagers is generally twice that of an ale.  However, pitching onto a used yeast cake generally results in overpitching by a factor of around 100.  Overpitching by this amount is never recommended.

In any case, it does make beer, and works for both ales and lagers with the same effects.

Comment: I was going to say: "No there is no difference. Both cases are bad ideas."

Answer (score 1):

Some people make a 2 gallon batch of lager and ferment it warm, then just pour the beer off the yeast/trub directly down the sink and pitch the "real" lager wort on that cake. I'd say if the original batch was 5 gallons, then split the cake into thirds. Pitch on one and store the other two (after washing) in the fridge for your next lager starter.